# "Error while trying to run project: Unable to start program". Can run program only once. Then VS needs restart

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I'm running my .NET 4.0 (C#) project in debug mode after I start VS2013. It runs just fine.

The second time I start it from VS, I get the Dialog box that says `"Error while trying to run project: Unable to start program C:\path\to\file.exe"`

The process is still alive in the Taskmanager when I dismiss the dialog box.
From Windows Explorer, I can run the program just fine. And after closing it, the process is gone too from the Task Manager.

A rebuild doesn't help.
Is this a common problem with a known solution?

Comment: Maybe your program isn't actually exiting. What does it do?

Comment: It wont even start a second time after I manually end the process in  the TaskManager. It exits when I click the upper right red X and the `MainWindow.Closing` method runs without errors.

Comment: in my case the VPN screwed up something

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error while trying to run project: Unable to start program. The request is not supported](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43002441/error-while-trying-to-run-project-unable-to-start-program-the-request-is-not-s)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had an issue similar to this and I had to clear the component cache instruction can be found [Here](https://github.com/Codealike/Codealike-KnowledgeBase/blob/master/clear-visual-studio-component-cache.md).

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

For my case, it cause by `Platform target`, you could force choose it to `x86` or `x64` which your project is:

```
Each Project's Properties > Build > Platform target
```

Answer (score 2):

As I pointed out also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43002441/error-while-trying-to-run-project-unable-to-start-program-the-request-is-not-s#comment100706254_53702356), the only solution that worked for me was to disable the ConEmu integration:

> ConEmu → Settings → Integration → Default term → disable `Force ConEmu as default terminal for console applications`

Some users [reported](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53702356/3873799) that it was enough for them to disable the `Aggressive mode` in that same settings tab; that wasn't the case for me though.

Answer (score 1):

The topic is old, but this might help someone else.

So in my case I made a file in Visual Studio with .cp extension (accidentally deleted the last 'p') this made visual studio just "include" the the file and not mark it as a compilation unit, thus not compiling it, I looked the *.vcxproj file in a text editor and found out about this, so if you open the project file in a notepad or something just find your file at the bottom usually and change from *<Item .../>* to *<ClCompile .../>*

Answer (score 0):

I was getting similar errors. I just had to restart visual studio. Sometime couple times a day.

Comment: Yeah the problem is I have to do it every time that I want to run my program after I closed it the first time.

Comment: I didn't find any solution to that. Just went to 2015. I remember that there were really bad days when I needed to restart VS every time.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar error and resolved it by cleaning the solution.  Right-click the solution name in Solution Explorer and choose Clean Solution.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/d202027b-32cf-4a55-9511-ffe6fefc0c06/error-while-trying-to-run-project-unable-to-start-program-the-request-is-not-supported?forum=vsdebug):

> Please check "Use Managed Compatibility Mode" under Tools|->Options->Debugging->General.

Comment: As pointed out also [here],(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43002441/error-while-trying-to-run-project-unable-to-start-program-the-request-is-not-s#comment100706152_43002574) this did work for me, however **you lose the Edit and Continue feature**, which is a no-go for me.
I then did find the [right solution for me](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43002441/error-while-trying-to-run-project-unable-to-start-program-the-request-is-not-s#comment100706254_53702356), which had to do with **Conemu**.

Answer (score 0):

I'm Brazilian, I don't speak English very well. I did this translation on google translator.
I know the topic is old, but it can still help someone.
I had this same problem in the following situation, I have a dual boot computer (linux debian 11 and windows 10). Inside debian, on my NTFS D disk, I created a folder to perform programming tests. After accessing that same folder with windows, I created a new project in visual studio inside that same folder that I had created in linux. The creation of the project went without problems, however when I tried to run the project (F5), I received the same error from this topic. I tried all the solutions I found on the internet, and nothing worked. I gave all permissions to my admin user and it still didn't work. Then I realized that even going straight to the folder where the application's executable was and clicking directly on it, I still received the access denied error message. So, I took the project out of the folder I had created in linux, and it worked. So, what I could conclude, is that because the folder where my project was was created in linux, for some reason, my windows didn't trust this folder, so it didn't allow running executables from inside that folder, even this one executable having been created by visual studio from within windows.

Answer (score 0):

Just simply create a folder name as "projects" in c drive and copy paste the newly created project in it. Run the project by doing clean & Build or Rebuild method . It will work

Answer (score 0):

1. open the folder which contains the solution in visual studio.
2. again, open your *.sln file by double clicking it inside the solution explore once opened try running the solution or rebuild the solution. once rebuild gets completed, it will open without error from next time.

Answer (score 0):

My way of solving the error : error while trying to load project : Unable to start program and c:\Path\to\file.exe was simply by

1. First restart Visual Studio
2. Click the build icon
3. Select the rebuild option
4. Run the Program or Debug the Program

Answer (score 0):

This was a weird one. Going to put what happened to me here because it might happen to someone else. Everything was fine with the app until suddenly after some fairly insignificant code changes I suddenly started getting this error. Visual Studio was compiling the executable just fine. But, the moment I tried to run it (either from Visual Studio or directly) the executable file would be automatically deleted right out of the Debug folder. Super odd--never seen anything like it. I began to get suspicious that perhaps an anti-virus or the OS was somehow identifying a checksum or some signature in the executable as "dangerous". Or perhaps some obscure compilation bug was corrupting the executable. So on a hunch I made another innocuous change (added a couple of lines of code to color code some text in a rich text box) and the problem went away.